# Retry a transaction on Candy Machine

Tags: solana, metaplex, solana-cli, candy-machine, solana-transaction-instruction

I am just finishing an upload of 8000 assets to candy machine (via the upload command). Everything seemed to be working well when it was creating the bundles and saving them to the cache, but once it started to write the indices I've started seeing these two errors on and off:

1)

```
Waiting 5 seconds to check Bundlr balance.
Requesting a withdrawal of 0.638239951 SOL from Bundlr...
Successfully withdrew 0.638244951 SOL.
Writing all indices in 719 transactions...
Progress: [█░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░] 2% | 18/719Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found
```

2. 

```
Failed writing indices 3682-3691: Transaction was not confirmed in 60.01 seconds. It is unknown if it succeeded or fail.
```

I have been searching the internet and from what I can tell these errors are out of my control..is this correct? Or what can I do to get these indices to write successfully? Its at 50% progress right now but I assume the upload is not going to be successful when it finishes. If this is the case, do I need to run the candy machine upload command all over again or is there a way for me to just run the transaction portion (where it started to fail) again? I've seen some notes on retry but it wasn't completely clear to me.

The upload process took about 2.5 hours so would like to avoid that if at all possible.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both errors are common so you dont have to worry about it. You should use a custom RPC (using `--rpc-url` on the upload command) and wait till the upload command ends. When the upload command ends you have to use `verify_upload` command in order to see if everything went well (if verify_upload shows an error you have to run upload again and repet till verify_upload shows `ready to deploy` message).

Comment: I was just going to post my upload command, this is what I ran: `ts-node /metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e mainnet-beta -k ./payer.json -cp config.json --rpc-url https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net -c example ./assets`...

Comment: Looks like it withdrew the SOL it needed so I'm assuming its not an issue with my SOL balance when writing the indices...

Comment: blockhash and time outs are more related to solana network errors that will be fixed trying again after use verify_upload

Comment: OK yea it finished the upload and it said `Done. Successful = false`. Which I expected. I then ran the `verify_upload`  and it came back with: `Error: not all NFTs checked out. check out logs above for details`. Which again I expected. I'm running upload again and am alreading seeing the same error `Transaction not confirmed in 60 sec`. If I see that error right away can I jut stop the upload command and run it again or should I let it finish regardless?

Comment: You will have to keep running those command till it work :c